# Xamarin forms Grid free spac adding at top with Xaml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have xaml page with this lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppXamaringOfficial;assembly=AppXamaringOfficial"
                       x:Class="AppXamaringOfficial.HelloXamlPage"
             Title="XXX">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <OnPlatform x:Key="textColor"
                 x:TypeArguments="Color"
                 iOS="Red"
                 Android="Aqua"
                 WinPhone="#EB099F" />

      <OnPlatform x:Key="backColor" x:TypeArguments="Color">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>#FFFFFF</OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>#FFFFFF</OnPlatform.Android>
        <OnPlatform.WinPhone>#FFFFFF</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
      </OnPlatform>

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#EDEDED">

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0, -20, 0, 0" BackgroundColor="#C5EEFC">

      <Grid.BindingContext>
        <local:KeypadViewModel />
      </Grid.BindingContext>

      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        <RowDefinition Height="120" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Button Text="1"
              Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
              CommandParameter="1"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
              WidthRequest ="120"
              HeightRequest ="120"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />

      <Button Text="2"
              Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
              CommandParameter="2"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
              WidthRequest ="120"
              HeightRequest ="120"
              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

      <Button Text="1"
            Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
            CommandParameter="1"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
            WidthRequest ="120"
            HeightRequest ="120"
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />

      <Button Text="2"
              Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
              CommandParameter="2"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
              WidthRequest ="120"
              HeightRequest ="120"
              Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />



      <Button Text="1"
        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
        CommandParameter="1"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
        WidthRequest ="120"
        HeightRequest ="120"
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />

      <Button Text="2"
              Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
              CommandParameter="2"
              BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
              WidthRequest ="120"
              HeightRequest ="120"
              Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />

    </Grid>

  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But when i run it on Android Device it adds free space at the top of Grid. Have i done mistake on XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 rows in your grid with a `Height` of 120 pixels each, but you are locating the objects inside of the grid by using the row 1 instead of 0 as the top most as seen in this piece of code:

```
...
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
    <RowDefinition Height="120" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button Text="1"
        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
        CommandParameter="1"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backColor}"
        WidthRequest ="120"
        HeightRequest ="120"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />  <!-- HERE!!! It should be Row 0! -->
...
```

In a collection, such as [RowsDefinitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowdefinitions.aspx) for a `Grid` object, the first index or child is located at the position 0 instead of 1.

**If the code you posted is correct, then you will always have an empty line of 120 pixels height, which belongs to the unused row 0 of the grid.**

If you want to solve this, then use `Grid.Row="0"`, `Grid.Row="1"` and `Grid.Row="2"` respectively on your objects instead of `Grid.Row="1"`, `Grid.Row="2"` and `Grid.Row="3"`.

Answer (score 1):

Apply below list of udpates in your code

1. Add `RowSpacing` & `ColumnSpacing` of `<Grid>` property to 0 and also Grid Rows starts from 0 index and not the 1
2. While defining height of grid row, keep last row as `*` instead of defining to some constants [here you've given 120
3. set `VerticalOptions="Start"` of the  property.

Hope this helps!